# According to Buddhism ,what is God?

Tags: god

If I am not wrong ,Buddhism denies God. But I am not sure what is the kind of God which Buddha denied ?

My question is : According to Buddhism what is God ? ( Any scriptural reference would be great.)

Comment: Also along with the duplicate question....god is devas in some indian language translations....so in this case god also means devas like indra and all...

Comment: I was looking for scriptural reference where Buddha explicitly denies any God whether Indra or Jesus or Krishna or Allah etc.

Comment: “God” has many definitions. One definition is of a omnipotent and omniscient creator of the universe. The Buddha has denied this exists or is even possible. Another is of a “god” as supernatural non-human being or beings. The Buddha does not deny this and in fact has supported the existence of these. Other definitions of “god” are possible...

Comment: @YesheTenley nice answer. Any reference to suttas ? (Original question mentions jataka tales)

Comment: For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.